# How to apply to background-image to only one react page not whole application?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

**Sample of Registration page:**

```css
.register{
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#ff5722 0%,#ff9800 100%);
margin-top: 150px !important;
}
```

```html
<div className="register">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-10 offset=md-1">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-md-5 register-left">
                                        <h3>Join Us</h3>
                                        <p>Subscribe</p>
                                        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button">About Us</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Sample of Default Layout (Core_ui Code Structure)

```
<div className="app">
            Header
            <div className="app-body">
                <main className="main">
                    <Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
                        <Switch>
                            {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                                return route.component ? (
                                    <Route
                                        key={idx}
                                        path={route.path}
                                        exact={route.exact}
                                        name={route.name}
                                        render={props => (
                                            <route.component {...props} />
                                        )} />
                                ) : (null);
                            })}
                            {/* <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" /> */}
                        </Switch>
                    </Suspense>
                </main>
            </div>
            <Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
                Footer
            </Suspense>
        </div>
```

I followed **coreui** code structure. and my app.css is empty. I created **register.css** and applied background but
CSS applied to only container part instead of full page.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem to a JSFIDDLE?

Comment: i can't understand your question can you explain more?

Comment: Implement routing with components for single route and in component register set custom css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example how add routing and custom style for any page:

> App:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route
          render={({ location }) => (
            <div>
              <Switch key={location.key} location={location}>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

> Home:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        home
        <br />
        <Link to="/register">register</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to="/login">login</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

> Login:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        // here add you custom style for page
        style={{
          backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to right,#ff8733 0%,#fa1100 100%)",
          height: 100,
          marginTop: 10,
          textAlign: "center"
        }}
      >
        Login
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

> Register:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Register extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        // here add you custom style for page
        style={{
          backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to right,#ff5722 0%,#ff9800 100%)",
          height: 100,
          marginTop: 10,
          textAlign: "center"
        }}
      >
        Register
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Register;
```

Online example:

[image: Edit styling example]

---

*UPDATE*

to have full window div with background gradient:
`npm install style.css`

after create `style.css` with `body { margin: 0, padding: 0 }` import this file in `index.js` : `import "style.css";`

After update styles for Login and Register component:

```
//...
style={{
  //...
  height: "100vh",
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  // ....
}}
//...
```

Comment: Add `import 'style.css';` on index.js. See example. I'm update codeSanbox

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way is probably using CSS class.

1. add this class in your styles.css

```
.full-screen {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  // or "height: auto" if page is large and you need to scrool down to see all content
}

.bg-home {
  background-image: url("./assets/images/black-linen.png");
}
```

2. in very first `<div>` element (where its return from function) add your classes

```
import `{ ButtonLogin, ButtonRegister }` from "../../components/Button";


function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='full-screen bg-home'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='buttons-div'>
          <ButtonLogin />
          <ButtonRegister />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```